# TeamCity Visual Studio Build Runner Requirement

Tags: visual-studio, build, teamcity, build-server, teamcity-9.0

We're running TeamCity 9.0.3 and have had Visual Studio 2010, 2012 & 2013 full install on our build server for years now.

I know for a fact that we need certain Visual Studio targets in order to deploy our applications but I'm convinced we don't need to have a full Visual Studio installation in order to use the Visual Studio (sln) build runner but can't find any documentation to say whether or not we do need it.

Can anyone show me documentation or verify from their own experience whether or not a full Visual Studio install is needed for this build runner to work?

---

Edit: I have seen this question:
[Does MSbuild require Visual Studio to be installed on the build server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483589/msbuild-requires-visual-studio-installed-on-build-server)

And mine is not the same question, it's a different topic. That question is asking whether or not Visual Studio is needed to as a prerequisite for the **MSBuild build runner**. My question pertains to the **Visual Studio build runner**

Comment: The version of Visual Studio matters a lot so you should be more specific on which version you are referring to.

Comment: I've updated my question with the versions. I don't think it'll narrow anything down though, besides, the point of the question is to find out whether or any VS install is needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSbuild requires Visual studio installed on build server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483589/msbuild-requires-visual-studio-installed-on-build-server)

Comment: I've seen this question before I asked mine, it's a different topic. That question is asking whether or not VS is needed to as a prerequisite for the MSBuild build runner. Not the Visual Studio build runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio (sln) build runner requires the proper version of Microsoft Visual Studio installed on the build agent.

Reference: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=74847254

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, by installing Windows SDKs you get what's required to build applications.

- [Windows 7 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
- [Windows 8.1 SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx)
- [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

[Multi targeting packs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx#) are also required if you use that.

Starting from Visual Studio 2013, you also need to install the separate [MSBuild 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760). And [MSBuild 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159).

C++ might require you to install other bits.

So you will have to go through lots of trials. Most people simply give up and install full VS.

Comment: Good answer, I'm looking for definitive proof though. I've found plenty of conjecture around the subject but nothing from Microsoft or TeamCity to confirm this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need full Visual Studio Installed for running the build, all you need are the build tools.

In the "Step" you create to build your solution, the dropdown allows you to select which version of Microsoft builds you want to use where you can specify whether you use MSBuild12 or the latest MSBuild14 for VS2015 projects.

All you have to do is make sure that you install the required Microsoft Build tools in this instance:
Build tools for 2010, 2012 and 2013. The TC build step should then try detecting this install by default in C:/Program Files (x86)/MS Build/Build Tool Number/MSBuild.exe

Note: You will have to restart your agent after you install these tools on the Agent Machine for TeamCity to detect the tools.

Comment: Great answer, it will take some time for me to verify this though. If our builds run as expected after uninstalling all VS instances and just having MSBuild installed then I'll mark this as the correct answer

Comment: I hope this helps. Here is a link for MSbuild tools 2013: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40760