# How to instantiate a type with many constructors with the same amount of parameters in Spring.Net

Tags: c#, spring, spring.net

I want to instantiate a `System.Net.IPEndPoint` with Spring.Net. 
Here is my xml code:

```xml
<object id="MulticastAddress" type="System.Net.IPAddress" factory-method="Parse">
  <constructor-arg value="239.239.239.1"/>
</object>
<object id="DestinationEndPoint" type="System.Net.IPEndPoint">
  <constructor-arg name="address" ref="MulticastAddress"/>
  <constructor-arg name="port" value="2010"/>
</object>
```

But this causes a `Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException` with additional information: Cannot convert property value of type [System.Net.IPAddress] to required type [System.Int64] for property ''.

IPEndPoint has two constructors:

```
public IPEndPoint(long address, int port);
public IPEndPoint(IPAddress address, int port);
```

It seems that spring uses the first constructor which is actually a bad idea.

So how can I tell spring that it should use the second constructor?

**Update :**

I figured out how to convert the IPAddress into a long:

```
<object id="DestinationEndPoint" type="System.Net.IPEndPoint">
  <constructor-arg name="address" expression="T(System.Net.IPAddress).Parse('239.239.239.1')"/>
  <constructor-arg name="port" value="2010"/>
</object>
```

But now I got the exception: Cannot convert property value of type [System.Int64] to required type [System.Net.IPAddress] for property ''.

Now it seems that Spring uses the other constructor. What is it!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by my self. Spring.Net is throwing this exceptions if a constructor does not fit to the passed arguments. But Spring.Net is catching this exception later and tries the next constructor. So my problem was that I has to tell VisualStudio that it shouldn't break by this exception -_-.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I will ask the guys from Microsoft directly. I just thought because there are related questions here like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779604/is-a-separate-visual-studio-license-required-for-a-build-machine I could have get an answer too.

Comment: You can get answers here. Maybe even perfectly correct answers. But they would still be outside the scope of the site ... so I agree: better ask folks at MS. When they you something wrong ... then they did that ;-)