# Failed to locate the code coverage command line tool , MSBuild with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube-msbuild-runner, sonarqube5.3

Getting the following error's once build is triggered from the build definition.

```
3:46:16 AM  Failed to locate the code coverage command line tool Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
Exception Message: TF270015: 'MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:
   at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I am using SonarQube 5.3, installed in the build server. I have .net framework installed in build server not the visual studio .

[BuildDefinition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raUJg.jpg) where I am referencing SonarQube.

Please help me here !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code coverage tools are installed with Visual Studio not the .Net Framework, so if you want code coverage you'll need to install VS on the build agent.
Depending on the version of Visual Studio you are using, you may not need an additional license for build agent. See the discussion [Is a separate Visual Studio license required for a build machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779604/is-a-separate-visual-studio-license-required-for-a-build-machine) get more detail.